# One coding problem two different solutions, how to prove is correct?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, kotlin, math

I have a coding problem:

The awards committee of your alma mater (i.e. your college/university) asked for your assistance with a budget allocation problem they’re facing. Originally, the committee planned to give N research grants this year. However, due to spending cutbacks, the budget was reduced to newBudget dollars and now they need to reallocate the grants. The committee made a decision that they’d like to impact as few grant recipients as possible by applying a maximum cap on all grants. Every grant initially planned to be higher than cap will now be exactly cap dollars. Grants less or equal to cap, obviously, won’t be impacted.

Given an array grantsArray of the original grants and the reduced budget newBudget, write a function findGrantsCap that finds in the most efficient manner a cap such that the least number of recipients is impacted and that the new budget constraint is met (i.e. sum of the N reallocated grants equals to newBudget).

Analyse the time and space complexities of your solution.

Example:

input:  `grantsArray = [2, 100, 50, 120, 1000]`, newBudget = `190`

output: `47`

The recommended solution is:

```
fun findCorrectGrantsCap(grantsArray: DoubleArray, newBudget: Double): Double {
        grantsArray.sortDescending()
        val grantsArray = grantsArray + 0.0
        var surplus = grantsArray.sum() - newBudget
        if (surplus <= 0)
                return grantsArray[0]
        var lastIndex = 0
        for(i in 0 until grantsArray.lastIndex) {
                lastIndex = i
                surplus -= (i+1) * (grantsArray[i] - grantsArray[i+1])
                if (surplus <= 0)
                        break
        }
        return grantsArray[lastIndex+1] + (-surplus / (lastIndex.toDouble()+1))
}
```

Compact and complexity is O(nlogn)

I came across with O(n) solution with tiny fractional part difference in the result between suggested solution and my one:

```
fun DoubleArray.calcSumAndCount(averageCap: Double, round: Boolean): Pair<Double, Int> {
        var count = 0
        var sum = 0.0
        forEach {
                if(round && it > round(averageCap))
                        count++
                else if(!round && it > averageCap)
                        count++
                else
                        sum+=it
        }
        return sum to count
}

fun Pair<Double, Int>.calcCap(budget: Double)  =
        (budget-first)/second

fun findGrantsCap(grantsArray: DoubleArray, newBudget: Double): Double {
        if(grantsArray.isEmpty())
            return 0.0
        val averageCap = newBudget/grantsArray.size
        if(grantsArray.sum() <= newBudget)
                return grantsArray.maxOf { it }
        var sumAndCount = grantsArray.calcSumAndCount(averageCap, false)
        val cap =  sumAndCount.calcCap(newBudget)
        val finalSum = grantsArray.sumOf {
                if(it > cap)
                        cap
                else it
        }
        return if(finalSum == newBudget)
                cap
        else
                grantsArray
                        .calcSumAndCount(averageCap, true)
                        .calcCap(newBudget)
}
```

I wonder if any test case to prove that my solution incorrect or vice versa is correct since provided approaches to solve this coding problem completely different.
Original source doesn't provide reach test cases.

**UPDATE**

As *PaulHankin* suggested I wrote simple test:

```
 repeat(1000000) {
                val grants = (0..Random.nextInt(6)).map { Random.nextDouble(0.0, 9000000000.0) }.toDoubleArray()
                val newBudget = Random.nextDouble(0.0, 9000000000.0)
                val cap1 = findCorrectGrantsCap(grants, newBudget)
                val cap2 = findGrantsCap(grants, newBudget)
                if (abs(cap1 - cap2) > .00001)
                        println("FAILED: $cap1 != $cap2 (${grants.joinToString()}), $newBudget")
        }
```

And it's failed he is right. But when I redesigned my solution:

```
fun findGrantsCap(grantsArray: DoubleArray, newBudget: Double): Double {
        if(grantsArray.isEmpty())
                return 0.0
        if(grantsArray.sum() <= newBudget)
                return grantsArray.maxOf { it }
        grantsArray.sort()
        var size = grantsArray.size
        var averageCap = newBudget/size
        var tempBudget = newBudget
        for(grant in grantsArray) {
                if(grant <= averageCap) {
                        size--
                        tempBudget -= grant
                        averageCap = tempBudget/size
                } else break

        }

        return averageCap
}
```

After that the test cases pass successfully, the only problem with double precision/overflow error if I use large Doubles if increase limits of input for  grants and/or budget (it can be fixed using BigDecimal instead for large inputs).

So the latest solution is correct now? Or is still can be some test cases where it can be failed?

Comment: Your answer looks like it computes the cap as the new budget divided by the number of grants, or a rounded version of that. It seems like that can't be correct, and I expect you can construct a test case by starting with some case where your algorithm works, and then adding lots of tiny grants of size 1.

Comment: Given that you have known working code (the solution you provide), a very easy way to generate test cases is to simply generate random arrays of small size (maybe 3 to 6), and a random budget and see if your code produces the same result as the correct code. You should be able to write code that tries millions of examples, stopping and printing out the example when the code differs. (Probably you want the code to stop at that point, since your code I believe is very wrong, and your terminal will be flooded).

Comment: There is a linear solution based on modified quickselect.

Comment: @PaulHankin I just edited the question (read latest part of it). Could you provide please some extra test case example if my latest solution is still failed?

Comment: It doesn't look right, although it may be right. How did you invent this method of computing the result? What's the mathematical reasoning that underlies your solution? If you can explain why you think it's correct in words or in abstract terms, perhaps that leads you to a mathematical argument why it's correct (or not).